# The difference between .value and .nodeValue

Tags: javascript

I add the JavaScript code needed to enable auto-complete on this form.

```
<form>
    <label for='shippingName'>Name</label>
    <input type='text' id='shippingName' name='shippingName' required></br></br>          
</form>
<form>
    <input type='checkbox' id='same' name='same' onchange='billingFunction()'>
    <label for='same'>Is the Billing Information the Same?</label>  
    <label for='billingName'>Name</label>
    <input type='text' id='billingName' name='billingName'></br></br>    
    <input type='submit' value='Verify'>
</form>
```

My script:

```
function billingFunction(){
    if(document.getElementById('same').checked) {
        var name = document.getElementById('shippingName').value;     
        document.getElementById('billingName').value = name;        
    }else{
        document.getElementById('billingName').value = "";        
    }
}
```

My question is if I use .nodeValue instead .value in var name, the function does not work. What is the difference bettween them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue) is not supposed to be used to get the values of inputs, it's meant to get the data of text nodes and things such as data sections.